# Use date parameter in Azure Pipeline FetchXML query

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-data-factory, fetchxml

in my Azure Data Factory pipeline, I have a parameter, let's call it '*pDate*', and it has a default value of *2023-01-01*.

But every time I run the pipeline (copy data), I want to be able to change it.

I can do that with a variable as shown below (*date1* variable), but then I have to change the value of the variable.

How could I insert a parameter here instead?

```css
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false"> 
<entity name="my_attachment"> 
<all-attributes/>  
<filter type="and"> 
<condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="@{variables('date1')}" /> 
</filter>  
</entity> 
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Parameters are constants across the particular pipeline. So, you can't change its value within the pipeline.
- A variable with static value (say `2023-01-01`) is a parameter itself. Every time you execute the pipeline, the same value will be assigned to the variable making its functionality similar to parameter.
- If there is a pattern for your date like created on or before 10 days (from today's date), then you can build a dynamic pipeline expression for this value. So, each time you run the pipeline, the value would be dynamic as required.
- If there is no such pattern, then you have to make use of parameters. You can still change the value each time you run the pipeline.
- When you try to trigger or debug the pipeline, the `pipeline run` tab will prompt you to enter the value for your parameter. You can simply give the required value and proceed accordingly.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="my_attachment">
<all-attributes/>
<filter type="and">
<condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="@{pipeline().parameters.req_date}" />
</filter>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

[image]